# Sql, Top N, Last N Rows Multiple Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

*My Query*

```
SELECT *
FROM NumberedTable
WHERE RowNumber <= @firstRowCount 
OR RowNumber IN (SELECT TOP (@lastRowCount) RowNumber  
                 FROM NumberedTable NUI 
                 ORDER BY NUI.RowNumber DESC)
```

Before this query, another query working. I'm setting row numbers in this query.

But, this query's result top n row and last n row for all record. I need FIRST N rows and LAST N rows for specific column filter in all records.

MY QUERY RESULT PICTURE!

ALL RECORDS  PICTURE!

I need first N rows and last N rows for all doctors ! Not use where condition !

Comment: ... Why are you setting `RowNumber`?  Is this something you plan on doing often?  Do you not have some sort of auto-gen id?

Comment: Row_Number an area where I've done for sorting. None importance. Numbered Table for all the records in the first and last N number of records you want to list.

Comment: What I'm getting at is, if you were going to run another sort, would you update `RowNumber`?  Where are these queries being run from?  If there's a possibility that multiple queries are going to update `RowNumber`, you're going to get some very strange results...

Comment: In a nutshell, the first and last rows of records in a table I want to take. However, according to the column name in the table I need to.

For David, the future first record and the last record ... marc next to the first and last records! only supposed to appear in the query results.

Comment: ...what?  And did you have some other data to add to your post?

Answer (score 3):

MAY BE LIKE THIS?

```
SELECT TOP N * FROM TBL ORDER BY ID ASC

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP N * FROM TBL ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: +1, just one remark, order in DB is not guaranteed, so a clause order by should be added in first query.

Comment: Row_Number a first come running queries. Sort guaranteed. But you do not see your query my job. I, for X field in a table you want to bring the first N and the last N records.

I want
http://imageshack.com/a/img23/8771/xjyq.jpg

result,
http://imageshack.com/a/img203/4630/5cje.jpg

Comment: sorry i didnt understand your language :)

Comment: you mean top n , where n depends on total record fetched?

Comment: In a nutshell, the first and last rows of records in a table I want to take. However, according to the column name in the table I need to.

For David, the future first record and the last record ... marc next to the first and last records! only supposed to appear in the query results.